# Using uncommon characters `$` and `_` in java Identifiers

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style, naming-conventions

Is there any catch in using these uncommon characters in Java identifiers? 
From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z  (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons,  the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024).  The $ character should be used only in mechanically
>   generated source code or,  rarely, to access pre-existing names on
>   legacy systems.

Does it means that these characters are obsolete? Or they are just reserved for special use cases. `_` is often used in static field names.

I'm trying to build small library which will base its behavior on field and method names. It will receive object parse its field names and decide how to act.
I can also make use of annotations. But there are difficulties in serialization (JAXB etc.). And also it's sometime easier and quicker to use descriptive field name (Convention over Configuration). So these rarely used characters could be useful in this case.

**UPDATE**

I intentionally didn't mention unicode characters. I consider unicode characters in identifier names at least inappropriate.

Comment: There are a lot more valid characters

Comment: I think you can also use numbers except for the first character.

Comment: You may use any Unicode letter, what about `à`.

Comment: I have updated my question. Of course, we can also use digits. But I think that digits aren't so rare in identifier names.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore is perfectly fine. I would avoid $ though. `$name` could conflict with some hidden/generated fields.

If your library requires that special fields in user classes are marked by underscore, that's probably ok. But you can imagine that two libraries have similar requirements and run in conflict.

Comment: Some Java shops use the underscore prefix to denote class global fields.  For some reason, these shops have an aversion to "this".

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: They're probably borrowing that from the C convention of marking some structure fields as "private" by using an underscore. (This doesn't actually prevent other code from accessing those fields, but it makes it clear that they're not supposed to.) In Java, people usually make *all* fields private, so this convention becomes less meaningful.